# How to query on object type in dojo?

Tags: javascript, dojo, dojox.grid

We can use dojo.query to get certain elements based of CSS selectors but how do we query on object types? 
For example, get all the TextBox elements on the page and then use dojo.connect to bind a function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not completely supported, yet there are two ways of doing it as i see it.

One, figure out which is the unique class for a TextBox (`.dijitTextBox`), call `dojo.query('.dijitTextBox')`, loop result `dojo.forEach` and get the widget with `dijit.getEnclosingWidget(domnode)`

```
var textboxArray = [];
dojo.forEach(dojo.query('.dijitTextBox'), function(domnode) {
  textboxArray.push(dijit.getEnclosingWidget(domnode));
});
```

Or two, loop the `dijit.registry._hash`, test `declaredClass`, if its `dijit.form.TextBox` - connect.

```
var textboxArray = dojo.filter(dijit.registry._hash, function(widget) {
  return widget.declaredClass && widget.declaredClass == 'dijit.form.TextBox';
})
```

Depending your setup, choose the most efficient one. The latter is commonly best - unless you have 100's of widgets in your page. The first will have to xpath all your elements of the page. Allthough, remember that dojo.query takes a second parameter as 'parentNode'

Comment: if youre lucky, you can even call .connect directly on the textboxArray from dojo.filter as its a NodeList as opposed to an array in the method using .push into array: `dojo.filter(dijit.registry._hash, function(w) { return w.declaredClass == 'textbox' }).connect('onFocus', focusCallback);`

Comment: thanks for the reply. I will try it out and accept your answer.